# How to identify illogical character strings/sentences

Tags: r, string, text

Suppose I have a dataset with each row containing a sentence stemming from an open-ended question in a very large survey (German and French). Most sentences (answers) are logical; i.e. meaningful combination of words. However, there are a few careless respondents who simply filled in illogical character strings of various kinds.

A useful first step would be to identify everything that is not a word or some other way to identify the illogical strings. Does a package exist that would facilitate this? How to approach this problem?

Example:

```
df <- structure(list(sentence = c("Das ist ein deutscher Satz.", "Ein kürzerer Satz", "34t34 t444tt", "C'est une sentence francaise", ".-......", "---2r13 1r-2r2")), .Names = c("sentence"), row.names = c(NA,6L), class = "data.frame")

head(df)
                      sentence
1  Das ist ein deutscher Satz.
2            Ein kürzerer Satz
3                  34t34 t444tt
4 C'est une sentence francaise
5                     .-......
6                ---2r13 1r-2r2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the share of a-z and A-Z to all characters and the number of words to detect sentences.

```
df$nonCharShare <- nchar(gsub("[[:alpha:] ]", "", df$sentence)) / nchar(df$sentence)
df$words <- lengths(strsplit(df$sentence, " ", TRUE))
df
#                      sentence nonCharShare words
#1  Das ist ein deutscher Satz.   0.03703704     5
#2            Ein kürzerer Satz   0.00000000     3
#3                  34t34t444tt   0.63636364     1
#4 C'est une sentence francaise   0.03571429     4
#5                     .-......   1.00000000     1
#6                ---2r131r-2r2   0.76923077     1
```

Comment: Nice, however this had problems with my personal nonsense inputs, which would be sth like "sdfksdf asdfjsda asdfjsdaf asfd".

Comment: Yes for sure it is not a dictionary and can not detect those inputs.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data also contains nonsesical strings like jay.sf described. But this is still a usefull starting point!

Answer (score 0):

Supposed you had a dictionary as a vector.

```
dict <- c("das", "deutscher", "ein", "est", "francaise", "ist", "kürzerer", 
          "satz", "sentence", "une")
```

You could paste that to a pattern

```
dict.pat <- paste(dict, collapse="|")
```

to use it to flag undesired entries using `grepl`.

```
df <- transform(df, flag=sapply(df$sentence, function(x) +(!grepl(dict.pat, x))))
df
#                       sentence flag
# 1  Das ist ein deutscher Satz.    0
# 2            Ein kürzerer Satz    0
# 3                  34t34t444tt    1
# 4 C'est une sentence francaise    0
# 5                     .-......    1
# 6                ---2r131r-2r2    1
```

That as a start. Of course, you need to think about what is "undesired".

You may also want to take a look into the [quanteda](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda/index.html) package.